# javascript is skipping every other integer in a for loop

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code that creates vertices in a loop.

```
for(var i=0; i<100; i++){
  graph.add_vertex();
}
```

and another piece of code that seeks to clear them

```
graph.clear();
```

A `vertex` calls the `getId()` function, which simply assigns a incremented number. `add_vertex` is the only function calling `getId()`.

`clear()` looks something like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<graph.V.length; i++){
    console.log(graph.V[i]);
    graph.V[i].remove();
}
```

and the output lists every other vertex. What could cause an error like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript loop only applying to every other element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457544/javascript-loop-only-applying-to-every-other-element)

Comment: Looks like you are both incrementing your array index, and removing items from the array. That would cause you to skip every other member.

Comment: Simple solution, do your for loop in reverse.

Comment: To solve the issue @David784 mentioned you should start at the end of your array and then increment down, you can remove the object because it doesn't matter as you increment downward. `for(var i=graph.V.length; i>=0; i--) {//code}`